# Ideas for large NXT projects

Tags: nxt, building, programming

I currently have 6 NXT sets. Can anyone think of some large scale projects that I could attempt using most of the NXT bricks and pieces together?

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed.

Comment: One interesting project would be to build a manufacturing process, e.g. use the 18 motors to automate the production of little Lego cars or planes. It's a big project though, I once started building a factory to assemble little Lego planes with the Lego sets from a summer camp I was working at, but the kids started complaining that I was using up all the pieces :)